# sql bigger parameter then specyfied - no error - just taking substring? why?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter, exception

I have some sql procedure (MSSQL 2019) if relevant

```sql
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] @tmp varchar(32)  AS
print @tmp
```

why when i do

```sql
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[test]
        @tmp = N'SSL99999999999999999999999999999900000006785999999999999999'
```

I se it use 32 chars substring in @tmp ?  `SSL99999999999999999999999999999`
And no exception that string or binary data would be truncated as i expected ?

Can i turn on such behavouur ? i would need this if possible ;)

Thanks and regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @i varchar(5)='ppppppppppp'
Select @i 
--- output ppppp (without any error)

Declare @t table(col varchar(5))
insert into @t values('pppppppppp')
Select * from @t

--Error message "string or binary data would be truncated"
```

So it is while insert or Update this error will come if column length is less.
When same thing is assign to any variable then length automatically get truncated without any warning or error.This is default behaviour

Comment: i see thank You. i guess there is no way / some directive etc to force in some cases to throw exception on this kind of errors?

Comment: @Dorian,Yes there is way out,you have to write your own logic to throw error,if data length exceed.Wait I am updating my answer.

Comment: this i known thanks ;) i was thinking about something like set auto_trunc off etc - i see oracle have something similar but guess mssql still not - strange a bit imho ;p –